# How can I create custom column in group-by then aggregation in pandas

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I have `DataFrame` in the following format.

```
| User          | CodeID        | Language |
| ------------- |---------------| -------- |
| foo           | 1             | C        |
| foo           | 2             | C        |
| foo           | 3             | CPP      |
| bar           | 4             | C        |
| bar           | 5             | CPP      |
| bar           | 6             | Java     |
| bar           | 7             | CPP      |
```

Now what I want is to calculate the number of codes in each language for each user. That is I want a `DataFrame` in the following format.

```
| User | C  | CPP | Java | Total |
| ---- | -- | --- | ---- | ----- |
| foo  | 2  | 1   | 0    | 3     |
| bar  | 1  | 2   | 1    | 4     |
```

> Point to be noted that the number of languages is dynamic. However, it is okay if someone can provide a solution with a fixed set of languages. **Thanks in advance**.

Comment: I wouldn't call that *'custom column(s)'*, just crosstabulation of the Language column

Comment: @smci I am newer to `pandas` and not that much familiar with these terminologies.

Comment: Parvez: sure. Welcome to SO

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use `crosstab` and calculate total

```
In [223]: pd.crosstab(df.User, df.Language).assign(Total=lambda x: x.sum(axis=1))
Out[223]:
Language  C  CPP  Java  Total
User
bar       1    2     1      4
foo       2    1     0      3
```

Or

```
In [247]: df.pivot_table(index='User', columns='Language', values='CodeID', 
                         aggfunc=len).assign(Total=lambda x: x.sum(1))
Out[247]:
Language    C  CPP  Java  Total
User
bar       1.0  2.0   1.0    4.0
foo       2.0  1.0   NaN    3.0
```

Or

```
In [250]: df.groupby(['User', 'Language']).size().unstack(fill_value=0)
Out[250]:
Language  C  CPP  Java
User
bar       1    2     1
foo       2    1     0
```

Comment: Great solve! Thanks again. However, I'll request two other improvisations. 

Firstly, removing the second order indexing. Probably it has a more specific name. But, I am new to `pandas`. Hope, you got what I want.

Secondly, I have `Language` values like `C++`, `C++ 4.0.0-8`, `C++ 4.3.2`. I want to consider them all as `CPP`. Similarly, `C` for both `C` and `C99`. How do I do that?